# How to create complex div elements using jquery and add results of json array into them

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

hello Iam new to jquery can anyone help please
what i want is to create a complex div and to display the content of json array in it and my div element should look like this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="div1">
<span class="list">
<span><img src="img1.png"  class=" thmbnail" /></span>
<ul class="content">
<li class="col">id here</li>
<li class="col" id="value" value="200" >name here</li>
<li class="manuplator "><button>-</button><input type="text" id="countholder"class="change" /><button>+</button></li>
</ul>
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

and my jquery looks like this

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
        url: "new1.php",
        data: { name: $('#name-typed').val()
             },
        success: function(response) {

jQuery('<div/>', {
    class: 'div1',
    text: response
    }).appendTo('.container');

jQuery('<span/>', {
class: 'list',
    text: response
}).appendTo('.div1');

var img = $('<img />', { 
  class:'thmbnail',
  src: 'img1.png',
  alt: 'MyAlt'
});
img.appendTo($('.list'));

jQuery('<ul/>', {
    class: 'content',
    text: response
}).appendTo('.list');
 }
});
```

and my php file new1.php looks like this

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,"table");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT id,name FROM names";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"] $row["name"] .;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: So what is the question ? Appending `ul-li` elements in `span` looks ugly to me..

Comment: to add the entire .div1 into container

Comment: You do not have `li` elements created in your script..Provided [script](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/r107nzgd/) does work..

Comment: yes i donot know how to append multiple li elements into ul  could you please help thank you in advance

Comment: You seem to have weak understanding of  jquery ajax and php. Go and learn them and practice thoroughly.